# Counting a specific character in a file with Scanner

Tags: java, character, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter a character, and count the number of instances said character appears in a given file. And display the number of times the character appears.

I'm really at a loss, and I'm sorry I don't have much code yet, just don't know where to go from here.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class CharCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int count = 0;
        char character;

        File file = new File("Characters.txt");
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a single character");
        character = keyboard.nextLine().charAt(0);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Which _specific part_ of it are you stuck with?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html ? Scanner is not used for buffered file io. Trying to do so would be silly.

Comment: Specifying the character and getting the program to count the number of times that character appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the below code to read from the file and check it with the character you've entered. `count` will contain the occurrences of the specified character.

```
try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
            for(int i=0; i<line.length();i++){
                if(line.charAt(i) == character){
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // File not found
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Couldn't read the file
    }
```

Comment: Small addition, can also use Commons Lang StringUtils.countMatches - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: @JarleHansen - Good option:) OP can choose to replace that part with `StringUtils.countMatches`, if required.